# find_elements_by_css_selector does not return all the elements python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using find_elements_by_css_path() in my python code to return all the elements in a table.  However, only a subset of that list is returned.  Why is this the case?  How can I return all the elements?  The issue is the same whether I use find_elements_by_css_path and find_elements_by_xpath.

Here is a snippet of how the table is setup:

```
<table id="table1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="table1__name">
    <a href="/browse/row1">row 1</a>
   </td>
    .. here contains more td tags
  </tr>
```

Here is an example of a row element that is not picked up by the selector:

```
<tr>
 <td class="table1__name">
   <a href="/browse/row7">row 7</a>
 </td>
 .. here contains more td tags
</tr>
```

Here is my python call:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_sector("#table1 > tbody > tr > td > a")
```

The table is set up this way for each row.  The find_elements_by_css_path seems to randomly skip certain rows.

Comment: Could you post the complete HTML code of the table including rows that are matched by the selector and which don't? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I've contained an example of a row that does not appear in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a caching issue.  A previous version of the page was opened when the python script was called.